# HTML validator error

Tags: html, validation

I want menu in my page to look like this: About us | Contacts | Map. And I have a code for it:

```
<div id="headermenu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a title="About us" href="index.php?id=about"><?php  echo $meniu['about']; ?></a></li> |
        <li> <a title="Contacts" href="index.php?id=contacts"><?php  echo $meniu['contacts']; ?></a></li> |
        <li><a title="Map" href="index.php?id=map"><?php  echo $meniu['map']; ?></a> <img alt="map icon" src="images/map_icon.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, HTML validator don't like this idea and gives me an error: "character data is not allowed here" and suggests to remove `|`. But I don't want to! What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this and work with margins to make it look good:

```html
<div id="headermenu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a title="About us" href="index.php?id=about"><?php  echo $meniu['about']; ?></a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li> <a title="Contacts" href="index.php?id=contacts"><?php  echo $meniu['contacts']; ?></a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a title="Map" href="index.php?id=map"><?php  echo $meniu['map']; ?></a> <img alt="map icon" src="images/map_icon.png" /></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Style the list to make list items appear  horizontally (e.g. `display: inline-block;`), and set their left or right border to `medium solid black`.

```
ul { display: block; }
li { display: inline-block; border-left: medium solid black;
     padding: 0 1ex; margin: 0; /* some spacing is nice */ }
li:first-child { border-left: none; }
```

There mustn't be any character data directly inside the `ul` element; only `li` elements are allowed there. So delete those bars.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try adding a `border-right` to the `li` elements. The last `li` doesn't need it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You could put it inside the `<li>`, since the validator is complaining about the text being outside it.

But the better solution might be to make a vertical bar using CSS, by setting a right border on all but the last `<li>` (give the last one a class, so you can clear the border setting just for that one).